# Display star rating in the asp.mvc ui table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins

I am working on an ASP.MVC application. I have to display Star Rating for the values in the database which start from 1 to 5. Based on the value, i need to display. UI also allow the users to rate their rating. Customer feedback rating feature. Need some tips from the experts.

Comment: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=custombindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you google "jquery star rating" you will find a number of plugins (I can't recommend a specific one). They provide callbacks and all so you pretty much just need to build functions to update your database with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Create a display/editor template with functionality to color stars in based on DB values, and to use a different color value if one of the DB values comes from the current user. Netflix has yellow for everyone else's ratings, and red for the current user's rating.

For help with display templates, look to Scott Hanselman's article:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx